# Postgresql get matched line of joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I have a table where we have partners and orders are set.

```
|partner_id|order_id|
| -------- | ------ |
|1         |5       |
|1         |6       |
|2         |7       |
|4         |8       |
|4         |9       |
|4         |10      |
```

Here we have a table where partner information is set. Here `id` is `partner_id` from previous table.

```
|id|email               |
|--| ------------------ |
|1 |some_email@email.com|
|2 |some_email@email.com|
|4 |email@email.com     |
```

My question is there a any possibility by joining these tables get something like:

```
|partner_id|email               |sale_count|
| -------- | ------------------ | -------- |
|1         |some_email@email.com| 3        |
|4         |email@email.com     | 3        |
```

Basically my goal is to match orders by partner email and extract one of the partners with the same emails `id`.

Comment: "One of the partners" is really unprecise! Which one do you want? It seems you need something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/DJZhktOz

Comment: Thanks! It worked well! Regarding "One of the partners" - yes, it's unprecise. But in my case it doesn't matter which one I'll take -  neither by id nor by name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.ID,COUNT(O.ORDER_ID)AS CNTT,P.EMAIL
FROM ORDERS AS O
JOIN PARTNER_INFORMATION AS P ON O.PARTNER_ID=P.ID
GROUP BY P.ID,P.EMAIL
```

ORDERS-a table where we have partners and orders are set.
PARTNER_INFORMATION -Here we have a table where partner information is set.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a distinct email, then you should try;

```
SELECT
    email,
    SUM(sale_count) AS total_sale_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        pe.email,
        COUNT(po.order_id) AS sale_count
    FROM
        partner_order AS po
    JOIN
        partner_email AS pe
    ON
        po.partner_id = pe.id
    GROUP BY
        pe.email
) AS subquery
GROUP BY
    email;
```

otherwise you can't group the different `id`s from the same email.